# how do I make my header so that when it leaves the page it toggles and back?

Tags: javascript

How do I make my header so that when it leaves the page it toggles like a menu and stays fixed on the page? [like this page](https://balterhost.com)

I thought it would work with this code :

```js
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (rect.top = 0);
}


var element = document.getElementById("header2");

function addClassOnScroll() {
  if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
    element.classList.add("in-viewport");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", addClassOnScroll);
window.addEventListener("scroll", addClassOnScroll, {
  passive: true
});
```

```css
#header2 {
  display: none;
}

.element.in-viewport {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make a [mcve]. It is not obvious what you want "when it leaves the page?". The site you posted does not seem to do anything special when scrolling.

Comment: `return (rect.top = 0);` — That's an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Split the header into 2 separate components. Lets call them `StaticHeader` and `FixedHeader`. The static header should have the CSS property of `position: relative` and the fixed one should have the property of `position: fixed`.

Now for the logic you will first need to find the height of your `StaticHeader`. You can hard code this by looking at it in the **browser dev tools** (inspect) or by getting the height of the object via JavaScript.

Getting the height of the element using JavaScript:

```js
const staticHeaderHeight = document.getElementById('static-header').offsetHeight;
```

In the layout it should look something like this:

```
<>
  <StaticHeader id="static-header" />
  <FixedHeader id="fixed-header" />
</>
```

Now you should add an `onScroll EventListener` and if the `scrollPosition` is equal to more than your `StaticHeader` height, you should display the `FixedHeader`.

```js
function showFixedHeader() {
  const fixedHeader = document.getElementById('fixed-header');
  
  fixedHeader.classList.add("in-viewport");
}

function hideFixedHeader() {
  const fixedHeader = document.getElementById('fixed-header');
  
  fixedHeader.classList.remove("in-viewport");
}

function handleChangeHeaderState() {
  const staticHeaderHeight = document.getElementById('static-header').offsetHeight;

  const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;

  if (currentScrollY >= staticHeaderHeight) {
    showFixedHeader();
  } else {
    hideFixedHeader();
  }
}

function checkScrollPosition() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleChangeHeaderState)
}
```

Note: I don't really code in plain JavaScript so it might be needed to change `consts` into `vars`. Also the CSS for fixed header should be `display: none` by default, just like you wrote in your post.